# Is it possible to 'refresh' WPF data bindings

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, refresh

I've got a xaml TabControl and on one page, there are 3 RadioButtons each bound to a different property on the selected value of an adjacent ListView. After switching between selected items in the ListView, my radio buttons seem to forget they're bound and don't refresh.

So watching it in the debugger, when I switch to a new selected item, I see the non user code first checking the value on all 3 properties, then only the first two, and eventually only the first. However, if I change the tab and change back, it seems to give me another few uses.

The binding itself is fairly straightforward. a TwoWay binding of a bool property to IsChecked. It's 4 levels deep (Path=DataModel.Selected.A.B), but I have other things at the same depth that work fine.

Is this something people have heard about and know what might be going on? Or if the binding is somehow getting forgotten, is there a way to explicitly remind the xaml?

Comment: After further research with Snoop, I can actually watch the binding disappear after several selection changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is apparently somewhat of a known issue:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8eb8280a-19c4-4502-8260-f74633a9e2f2/

In short, a RadioButton (through .Net 3.5sp1) somehow kills bindings of other RadioButtons when when it's checked while trying to uncheck any other buttons. The simple fix (read: hack) is to assign each radiobutton a different GroupName and then they don't try to mess with eachother

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to manually update bindings like this:

```
TestCheckBox
    .GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty)
    .UpdateTarget();
```

That being said, I don't have 100% confidence that this will correct your underlying issue. I haven't had this sort of issue before with WPF bindings, but I have had a couple *weird* issues with the tab control.

Comment: I'm more inclined to blame RadioButton than TabControl, but that's only because I've had other issues with it before. I'll try this for an interim fix though

Comment: Even doing this on every selection change, it doesn't seem to help, which kind of fits with the binding being completely lost theory

Answer (score 1):

Another way to resolve this issue is to fake up a list of properties in a ListBox and have the ListBoxItem template be a radiobutton.